# Python: re.findall no muestra cadenas de digitos correctamente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi estimados, llevo un rato en esto y quisiera saber qué estoy haciendo mal.

Tengo esta cadena

> /fichero/items/show/687/fichero/items/show/365/fichero/items/show/34/fichero/items/show/35/fichero/items/show/38/fichero/items/show/187/fichero/items/show/353/fichero/items/show/354/fichero/items/show/367/fichero/items/show/368/fichero/items/show/369/fichero/items/show/370/fichero/items/show/641/fichero/items/show/425/fichero/items/show/408/fichero/items/show/640/fichero/items/show/39/fichero/items/show/409/fichero/items/show/356/fichero/items/show/568/fichero/items/show/571/fichero/items/show/355/fichero/items/show/40/fichero/...

Y he querido encontrar los dígitos utilizando `re.findall(r'\d+', cadena)`. Pero el resultado es:

> 6,8,73,6,53,43,53,81,8,73,5,33,5,43,6,73,6,83,6,93,7,06,4,14,2,54,0,86,4,03,94,0,93,5,65,6,85,7,13,5,54,05,7,03,5,73,3,45,3,64,24,34,44,6,16,8,95,6,97,92,5,36,8,66,8,84,64,84,95,05,25,33,4,76,3,03,3,84,73,6,15,2,65,3,1

Y claro, yo quiero que sea `687,365,34,35...`

¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y funciona bien `['687', '365', '34', '35', '38', '187', '353', '354', '367', '368', '369', '370', '641', '425', '408', '640', '39', '409', '356', '568', '571', '355', '40']`

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio. En efecto, creo que el problema está en otro lado del código programa que estoy haciendo.